# Controlling the number of panels in a lattice plot with R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

How do I limit the number of panels shown on a single page using lattice? I am graphing the results of a regression for multiple states and putting 50 of these on a single page makes them unreadable. I would like to limit the output to 4 wide and as many tall as needed.

Here's my lattice code:

```
xyplot(Predicted_value + Actual_value ~ x_value | State_CD, data=dd)
```

There are 50 different values for State_CD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the `layout` parameter.

Maybe you want something like:

```
xyplot(Predicted_value + Actual_value ~ x_value | State_CD, data=dd, layout = c(4,5))
```

Comment: Bingo. I was hoping it was something easy like that. I kept browsing through Sarkar's book and just couldn't find it.